# Parsing string in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am asking for help for a query in ElasticSearch. I have entries in field `name` like:

```
/dir1/sub1/subsub1/file1
/dir1/sub1/subsub2/file2
/dir1/sub2/file3
```

Here I want to list objects in a specific directory. For example if I search by /dir1 I want to be returned:

```
sub1
sub2
```

or entire string but subdirectories shall not be repeated. I can use grouping but a problem is a parsing of string itself.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch provides [Path Hierarchy Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) which seems to be a suitable fit for  your problem of parsing strings

The path_hierarchy tokenizer takes something like this:

```
/something/something/else
```

And produces tokens:

```
/something
/something/something
/something/something/else
```